# Scale & Trig Programming Issue/Stuck

Tags: javascript, math, svg, raphael

I am really stuck on this problem I am having. I am trying to develop a scaling circle photo cropper that uses SVG and has two handles, one to make the crop circle bigger/smaller and one to move it around. The moving around part is simple, but the scaling is the issue.

https://skitch.com/sverbeek/ga5qt/photo.html

I have the above system setup, (notice the scale handle is the one not attached, as it has moved) and it moves along a plane of 65° (which may change later depending how it works). That part works fine, but now I am down to the nitty gritty of it. I get the different between where the scale tool started moving and where it ended in relate to X,Y (so for example 0,0 would be where it starts, if I move it up/right it goes from 0,0 to 10,-10 for example (negative Y and positive X) and the reverse for the other side).

But I need to somehow turn that difference in movement into a number between 0.3 and 2.3 where 0.# would be decreasing (going left/bottom) and 1/2.# would be going up/right. And I need it to be proportional to the handle so the handle is always attached.

But I'm so stuck I just can't figure out where to go. I made a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/FW4UB/

Comment: You mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/armkn/

Comment: I think I get it, the handles would move a little bit along the perimeter as you scale? But that would move the handles from under the cursor, why not place them along multiples of 45 degrees?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean Duopixel, now I guess it's a matter of cleaning it up some and solving the issue with the purple line scaling slower. May I ask what you changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the position of the scale handle you don't need trig, just invert the y axis. The x axis is the same as your scale tool:

```
i.handles.scaleTool.translate(newX-i.handles.scaleTool.ox,newY-i.handles.scaleTool.oy);
//Same formula except for a *-1 in the y axis
i.handles.dragTool.translate(newX-i.handles.scaleTool.ox,(newY-i.handles.scaleTool.oy)*-1);
```

To scale the circle accordingly you need to use Pythagoras theorem, which states that a2 + b2 = c2, which translated in your code looks like...

```
myset[0].attr({"r": Math.sqrt( Math.pow((myset[0].attr("cx")-cx),2) + Math.pow((myset[0].attr("cy")-cy),2))-15});
```

You can view the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/A3TPh/